# What is JavaScript FileReader and where it could be used?

Tags: javascript, file, filesystems

I saw somewhere someone talking about FileReader in JavaScript. What is it? What could be its use cases? Isn't it posing security problems, as it gives JavaScript access to disk?

```
  var temp = new FileReader();
  temp.onload = function(e){
      // Where did it load anything? 
  };
```

Comment: now where did you see this? It could be javascript that is not running in a browser, you know..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an HTML5 feature.  Check out the documentation here:

[HTML5 FileReader](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)

It's important to note that not all (IE) browser support this functionality.

Answer (score 2):

[FileReader on MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/FileReader). It's related to the HTML5 Blob and FileApi's. I'm pretty certain that a website can't just read random files, it can only read blobs that are basically user controlled (either from the site, or accessed via file APIs with consent)